# KeyError Pandas Merging .csv

Tags: python, pandas

I get the KeyError "ID123" all the time when running this code:

```
import pandas as pd

# Read the files into two dataframes.
df1 = pd.read_csv('Company.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('Contracts.csv')

print(df1)
print(df2)

# Merge the two dataframes, using _ID column as key
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = 'ID123', how='left')
df3.set_index('ID123', inplace = True)

# Write it to a new CSV file
df3.to_csv('merged.csv')
```

this is the output from printing the two dataframes:

```
    ID123;"Company_Name";"Country";"City";"Email";"Industry";"Employees"
0    217520699;"Enim Corp.";"Germany";"Bamberg";"po...                  
1    352428999;"Lacus Vestibulum Consulting";"Germa...                  
2    371718299;"Dictum Ultricies Ltd";"Germany";"An...                  
3    676789799;"A Consulting";"Germany";"Andernach"...                  
4    718526699;"Odio LLP";"Germany";"Eisenhüttensta...                  
..                                                 ...                  
595  99513212299;"Orci Inc.";"Germany";"Bremen";"am...                  
596  99653699699;"Elit Pretium Corp.";"Germany";"Fr...                  
597  99708720099;"Etiam Laoreet Institute";"Germany...                  
598  99770935599;"Nisi Corporation";"Germany";"Qued...                  
599  99957017899;"Dui Suspendisse Foundation";"Germ...                  

[600 rows x 1 columns]
    ID123;"CONTRACT_ID";"PRODUCT";"START_DATE";"END_DATE"
0       56613925699;06kNGt9aW1m5;EBP;24.12.18;24.12.19   
1       66987414399;0E8VENw82Fns;XTM;30.08.18;30.08.19   
2       89799152699;0HFC3eWqZ5NE;XTM;18.01.20;17.01.21   
3       61452128699;0RCk3qNQZLAq;EBP;17.01.18;17.01.19   
4       43710602699;0UNPblwlcHbt;EBP;20.12.19;19.12.20   
..                                                 ...   
628     33221128799;zalnNfamaQ91;XTM;26.05.20;26.05.21   
629     52613799699;ze0ipqL4CD2x;EBP;02.04.20;02.04.21   
630     78454735799;zhvJDZbwgkHL;EBP;08.02.19;08.02.20   
631     31691498899;zuVrMuOQOzUj;EBP;02.07.18;02.07.19   
632     77498119099;zzGhHds7rU21;EBP;04.04.20;04.04.21
```

please help! I tried many things but am totally stuck!

Comment: It's 'ID123' i guess not just 'ID'

Comment: sorry this was just a mistake in copying the code, of course the field value did match everywhere

Comment: looking at your sample,  it's all one column aa the CSV sep is semi-colon not comma